# Better Factorization

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

It seems Mathematica likes to factor some things in less than optimal ways. For example, for the oscillating exponential function (F) below, is there any way to force it to reduce both the number of exponential terms and appearance of constants like A? I can of course look at the result and manually rewrite it as function G, but this gets trickier for more complex equations.

```
F = A E^(-I t (\[Omega] + Subscript[\[Omega], 12])) (-1 + E^(I t (\[Omega] + Subscript[\[Omega], 12])))
Expand[F]
G = A*(1 - E^(-I t (\[Omega] + Subscript[\[Omega], 12])) )
Simplify[F == G]
Factor[Expand[F]]
```

[image]

Comment: Please upload more test cases.

Comment: Depending on your use cases, sometimes using `Collect` instead of `Factor` does the factoring that you want. For instance, `Collect[F, A, Simplify]` does things nicely.

Comment: ChaSta, `Factor`'s intended use is to factor in P[ℤ], it's certainly not the right function to use. @march, your answer is entirely correct. Would you like writing an answer?

Comment: @kkm-stillwaryofSEpromises I think without more use cases, I don't *know* if this is actually the correct answer. And if it *is*, I would suggest closing this question using the "found in documentation" close reason.

Comment: @march Right, I see. But I'd wait if OP could add more info early next week. Not everyone spends their weekends on MMA.SO (it's Saturday, 01:20 here :-)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it is not quite clear, what are you after. My guess is that you want to take `A` out of the parantheses, while the exponential term should stay intact, is it? If yes, try this:

```
Factor[(F // Simplify) /. E^(-I t (ω + ω12)) -> -x] /. 
 x -> -E^(-I t (ω + ω12))

(*  A (1 - E^(-I t (ω + ω12)))  *)
```

If it is not what you need, explain please clearer.

Have fun!

Comment: Yes, although I'm looking for a general form for this. The goal is to show as few terms as possible, without multiple A's or multiple Exponentials. I think the function below may be good enough, although in some cases it doesn't quite factor out -1*(-1)'s. Thanks!
Factor[Simplify[F] /. E^(y_) -> x[y]] /. x[y_] -> E^(y)

Answer (score 4):

You could also look into making a [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) which suits your needs.  This could be an example or starting point:

```
FullSimplify[F, 
 ComplexityFunction -> 
   (100 Count[#, A | Exp, {0, Infinity}] + 10 Count[#, (-1), {1}] + LeafCount[#] &)]
(* A (1 - E^(-I t (ω + Subscript[ω, 12]))) *)
```